# Letting a profile have many websites without making website its own resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, model

I want to let a profile have many websites (as just a url string), and for a user to fill in the websites into different text fields. However, I want this to be an attribute of the profile resource as opposed to its own resource. How can I set this up and how would I have access to the website strings in the profile view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will not need to search through these URL strings, look into **serialize**.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Serialize enables you to store multiple URLs in just one string. If, however, you want to be able to search through these URLs, I recommend you do go with a simple `Website` table with `id` and `url` fields.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Convention over configuration so you are going against the grain here.

As for the db, store it as a comma delimited string such as `User.websites_string`.

```
class User
    attr_accessor :website_one
    attr_accessor :website_two
    attr_accessor :webstie_three

before_save :parse_websites   

def prase_websites
    w1 = self.website_one ||= ""
    w2 = self.website_two ||= ""
    w3 = self.website_three ||= ""  
    self.websites = "#{w1}, #{w2}, #{w3} "
end

def websites
      self.websites_string.split(/[\s,]+/)
   end
end
```

Then in the views you will need to write your own method to have different `text_fields`.

```
<%= @form_for(user) do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.text_field :website_one %></p>
    <p><%= f.text_field :website_two %></p>
    <p><%= f.text_field :webstie_three %></p>
<% end %>
```

And if you want to have more websites you should think about meta programming. Really dry things up. But sites like linkedin, SO, twitter.... they usually don't have unlimited urls.

Comment: Also, how you you tweak this to allow users to add as many websites as he/she wants?

Comment: serialize is Rails' inbuilt (and typically elegant) way of doing just what you're specifying, but without this extra code and with the ability to add as many websites as the user wants. Even better, those websites can be added in one `text_area` separated by commas instead of needing discrete `text_fields` for each one.

Comment: I will have to check this out. I would have just one text field, but that is not what the question was after.

Answer (score 0):

Add new method to model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def web_sites_hash
    result = {}
    arr = web_sites.squish.split(' ') << ""
    arr.each_index {|i| result["web_site_#{i}"] = arr[i]}
    result
  end
end
```

Change view. Instead of this:

```
<%= f.label :web_sites %><br />
<%= f.text_area :web_sites %>
```

try this:

```
<%= f.label :web_sites %><br />
<% @profile.web_sites_hash.each_pair do |virt_field_name, virt_field_value| %>
  <%= f.text_field virt_field_name, :value => virt_field_value %><br />
<% end %>
```

Add to controller this block ('update' action for example)

```
def update
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])

  web_sites = []
  params[:profile].each_key do |prm_name|
    web_sites << params[:profile].delete(prm_name) if /^web_site_\d+$/ =~ prm_name      
  end
  params[:profile][:web_sites] = web_sites.join(' ').squish

  @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
  ...
end
```

In the view you can add more inputs with JavaScript. 
Here the sample: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2